# Multiple file uploads in nodejs using express-fileupload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, express-router, express-fileupload

Currently I am able to post this to mongodb. It works fine.

**PROBLEM**
Instead of one attachment, I should be able to post many attachments independent of each other, there will be N different buttons available for the N uploads.

```
const form = (req, res, next) => {

  const file = req.files.photo;

  file.name = `photo_${Math.random(0, 10012)}-${Math.random(0, 2000)}${
    path.parse(file.name).ext
  }`;

  file.mv(`./public/uploads/${file.name}`, async (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: `Problem With File Upload`,
      });
    }
    
    const upload = await Form.create({
       approved: req.body.approved,
       email_: req.body.email,

       formData: {
        name: "req.body.formData.claimantName",
        nationality: "req.body.formData.claimantNationality",
        address: "req.body.formData.claimantAddress",
        email: "req.body.formData.claimantEmail",
      }, 

      fileOne: file.name1,
          
      // these are the next 
      // fileTwo: req.body.formData.name2,
      // fileThree: req.body.formData.name3,

    });
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: `File Uploaded Successfully`,
      path: file.name,
    });
  });
};

router.route("/add").post(form);
```

I tried moving `const upload = await Form.create(...)` outside the `file.mv(...)` block and do somthing like this```
const file1 = req.files.photo1;

file1.name = `photo_${Math.random(0, 10012)}-${Math.random(0, 2000)}${ path.parse(file1.name).ext }`;

```
It doesn't work properly.
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can fetch the uploaded files in the `request` object in your node server on the endpoint which receives the request in `req.files` object.

**Your endpoint should catch files like this**

```
const uploads = Object.values(req.files);
```

As you're going to get an object of key value pairs as `key` will be file name `value` will be file data object containing name etc. `Object.values` will convert that object to an array of objects having the information of uploaded files. After that create a `promise` that will catch the files like shown below:

**Function to handle file uploads**

```
handleFileUpload = (uploads) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const dbData = [];
     uploads.forEach(async (upload) => {
       const name = await `photo_${Math.random(0, 10012)}-${Math.random(0, 2000
       )}${path.parse(upload.name).ext}`;
       dbData.push(name);
       await upload.mv(`your-path/${name}`, async (err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject("Something wrong");
        }
      });
   });
  resolve(dbData);
 });
};
```

After that pass in the uploads to the promise and make a db `insertion` in the `then` block.

```
handleFileUpload(uploads).then((response) => { ... }).catch((e) => { ... });
```

The `response` will have all the image paths.

**Note** : I'm considering the files to be `IMAGES`